# Gatling Scala: Reading JSON Data

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

How do I feed JSON data into Gatling Scala? This line of code will take in comma delimited csv. Trying to edit code for json below

```
object GetProductScenario {
  val csvData = csv("data/get_products.csv").circular

  def exportScenario(): ScenarioBuilder = {
    scenario("Get Products")
      .exec(
        forever() {
          feed(csvData)
            .exec(GetProducts.searchData())
        }
      )
  }
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "productId": 1,
  "name": "book",
  "amount": 17,
```

Comment: Gatling supports Json Feeders as well - https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/feeder/#json-feeders . So how about just using those ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at StringBody or ElFileBody where you can use patterns like `#{productId}` to inject the desired values.

https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#request-body
https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/el/

Comment: Do you have a working code example? SO does not like URLs as they often change, thanks

Comment: yeah, my @Dima my demonstrated code wasn't working, so it would be distraction from the question